# How to delete properly an object affected to a variable defined at import time with multiprocess?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process

PRODUCER_SINGLETON = None

def func_test():
    Producer.create_producer()


class Producer:
    @classmethod
    def create_producer(cls):
        global PRODUCER_SINGLETON
        if PRODUCER_SINGLETON is None:
            PRODUCER_SINGLETON = Producer()
        return PRODUCER_SINGLETON

    def __init__(self):
        print("got into produce")
        self.produce = "toto"

    def __del__(self):
        print("got into delete")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = Process(
        target=func_test,
    )
    process.start()
```

I want to create a variable at import time which will be used to pass along the Producer instance.
The problem is that if i use it with multiprocessing, the instance will never be deleted properly, i want it to be delete before the process end.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Many ways to do it - could have a single process own the shared resource and exit when nothing is using it, or could have a counter stored in OS managed memory/file and the last process to exit clears the resources.

Comment: in my example the producer is not serializable so i can't share it it need to be created inside the child process

Comment: If each child will have its own instance of a resource, just have the child dispose of its own resource instance.  Seems like you just need to get your architecture figured out - what resources each process uses, is responsible for releasing, etc.